# C++ variadic class templates and member functions

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, void

I'm having problems working around a problem in the following code...

```
#include <functional>

template<typename... ARGS>
class MyClass {
public :
    void function(ARGS... args)
    {
    }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    MyClass<int>        myClassInt;      // works fine
    MyClass<int, float> myClassIntFloat; // works fine
    MyClass<void>       myClassVoid;     // <---- won't compile

    return 0;
}
```

Clang quite rightly refusing to compile this if I instantiate MyClass on **void**, complaining that **MyClass<void>::function** is not a legal definition. However the real class I have needs to be able to instantiate this kind of thing on a void. I've been staring at this for ages and I'm stuck as to what template SFINAE jiggery-pokery I need to get around it.

Comment: I realise I need to specialise the **void** case in some way, but I can't see a way around it that won't be caught by the general variadic case.

Comment: Because using `void` is equivalent of declaring the member function `void MyClass::function(void args)` which is hardly valid. Specialization is indeed the key to solve your problem.

Comment: Why not `MyClass<>`?

Answer (score 4):

Either use `MyClass<>` at point of use, or this hack:

```
template<typename... ARGS>
class MyClass {
public :
  void function(ARGS... args)
  {}
};
template<>
class MyClass<void>:public MyClass<> {
public :
  using MyClass<>::MyClass; // inherit ctors
};
```

There may also be other things you need to do in `MyClass<void>` to act as a relatively transparent proxy to `MyClass<>`.

We can avoid those issues by not using `MyClass` directly.

```
template<typename... ARGS>
class MyClass_t {
public :
  void function(ARGS... args)
  {}
};

template<class...Args>
struct MyClass_helper {
  using type=MyClass_t<Args...>;
};
template<>
struct MyClass_helper<void>:MyClass_helper<> {};
template<class...Args>
using MyClass=typename MyClass_helper<Args...>::type;
```

now, `MyClass<void>` expands to `MyClass_t<>`, and `MyClass<int, float>` expands to `MyClass_t<int,float>`.

We don't directly use `MyClass_t`, instead we name it via `MyClass<...>`.  The downside to this technique is that `MyClass<???>` if used as a function argument is a non-deduced context; so you have to use `MyClass_t<???>` instead in those cases, and they won't see the `void`.

My preferred solution is to just use `MyClass<>` directly instead of `MyClass<void>`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I didn't know about instantiating it as MyClass<>, which seems to do the trick perfectly.